# Elliot suffers from which condition?

Tags: mr-robot

In Mr. Robot the main character, Elliot Alderson (Rami Malek) suffers from a condition such that he forgets like whole days, and not even one day, like 3 days straight.
What is this condition called?

Comment: Based on your question it seems like you have only watched season 1.  You should be aware that more and more information is revealed about Elliot Alderson's mental issues as time goes on and answers are likely to be spoiler-y.

Answer (score 1):

He suffers from [at least] 'dissociative identity disorder', what used to be called 'multiple personality disorder'. Probably also social anxiety disorder, if not also somewhere on the Autism spectrum, though this as far as I'm aware has never been officially stated. There is also an element of addiction and self-medication [morphine/opiates and suboxone].

I don't want to tell you any more, because if you haven't yet seen the end of season 1, it will ruin the end for you.

If you *have* already seen at least the first three seasons, there's a great explanation in a transcript of an interview with Sam Esmail, at [NPR.org - 'Mr. Robot' Creator Says His Own Anxiety And Hacking Helped Inspire The Show](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/774691659?t=1629368008535)
I would advise you *not* to read this if you aren't at least up to the end of season 3.
Also, from Popular Science - [‘Mr. Robot’ Creator Explains What’s Really Going On In Elliot’s Mind](https://www.popsci.com/mr-robot-creator-explains-whats-really-going-on-in-elliots-mind/) - again, don't read before at least season 3, though this is less spoilery than the previous link.